# Save lowagie.text.Image to File

Tags: java, itext

I have com.lowagie.text.Image Object and I want to save it to a file as PNG image.
I wonder whether it is possible or not to save it as a image file.I googled it but no luck. Anybody know how to save itext Image object to file?

**P.S:** I am not bothered about writing the Image object to PDF. I just want to save it as a image file(like png,jpg etc).

Comment: The `Image` type is only a wrapper. *Is* your object a PNG file? Then you can easily dump the bytes into a file using `Image#getOriginalData()`. Which is the second google hit. After the post-ancient class API.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your image was originally a PNG, you can just save the result of getOriginalData() to a file. Otherwise, you can build a BufferedImage first:

```
byte[] data = image.getOriginalData();
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", file);
```

Comment: *Otherwise, you can build a BufferedImage first* - only if it had been a bitmap image to start with. That class can also wrap different other structures, though.

Comment: Isn't ImageIO.write() method accepts RenderedImage as argument instead of BufferedImage. How to convert the BufferedImage to RenderedImage again..

Comment: a BufferedImage IS a RenderedImage